# POSTGRES: Find out how long a lock has been acquired

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I'm currently using Postgres as a database engine for an application.

I currently have a situation where I have a lot of READ locks (AccessSharedLocks) that are present. I run the following query to check for the locks:

```
SELECT t.schemaname,
t.relname,
l.locktype,
l.page,
l.virtualtransaction,
l.pid,
l.mode,
l.granted
FROM pg_locks l
 JOIN pg_stat_all_tables t ON l.relation = t.relid
WHERE t.schemaname <> 'pg_toast'::name AND t.schemaname <> 'pg_catalog'::name
```

What I would like to know is how long the lock was acquired for by a table. Is there any way that I can retrieve this information?

Comment: This view (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) might help you out you would need the `xact_start` column` which holds the transaction start time...  Then you can simply calculate

Comment: So am I correct in modifying the above query to join to the pg_stat_activity table on the pid column to use this property?

Comment: Yes you need to join pg_stat_activity view on the pid column

Comment: ok thanks. So just for my understanding, by using this xact_start field, would this be equivalent in saying that that this is the time that a lock has been acquired by a process which is used for this transaction?

Comment: `xact_start` displays `Time when this process' current transaction was **started**, or null if no transaction is active. If the current query is the first of its transaction, this column is equal to the query_start column.` The locking time could be different then the locking start time in thoery..

Comment: Just check these https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW views there might be a better one.

Comment: Locking time would be the same as transaction start time only if the locking was caused by the first operation in the transaction, otherwise it would be different.

Answer (score 1):

The time when a lock has been taken is not available in PostgreSQL.

The best you can do is to take the transaction start time `xact_start` from `pg_stat_activity`, that is a lower boundary for the age of the lock.

Transactions should always be short, because long transactions they hold locks and keep autovacuum from doing its job.

If you have any long running transactions, that might be the problem that you have to fix. Then the locks won't be such a problem.

Comment: Understood. thank you very much to Laurenz and Raymond